# How to properly get an AJAX request to React from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-3, axios

I'm fairly new to Rails, although I generally understand the structure/how it works. Side-note, my goal here is to have 1 javascript import tag in a `views/home/application.html.erb` that will import a single React file, which will then import the rest of my components in a tree-like structure. I'm used to this method because of my experience with Express so please let me know if this is not the standard way of doing things with Rails.

The current issue I'm facing however is that I can't/don't know how to get my Rails controller to send my instance variable as a response to my axios request. I'm expecting my browser to `console.log('TESTING MY RAILS ROUTE')`, but rather it's logging the entire HTML response.

**Index.jsx** (in javascript/components)

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


class Index extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/login')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Testing Axios</h1>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'welcome/index'

    resources :login

    root 'welcome#index'

end
```

**controllers/login_controller.rb**

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @test = 'TESTING MY RAILS ROUTE'
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb** (in views/welcome)

```
<%= react_component('Index') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your Rails controller to respond with `json` as it is currently responding with `HTML` type response.

Since you are using React with Rails, I'm assuming that you want your Rails API to always return JSON for React to render.

Using the `responders` gem can help simplify this implementation, and have less code in your controllers.

Add `gem 'responders'` to your `Gemfile`.
Also, identify the login resource in your `routes.db` to be json by default, like so:

`resources :login, defaults: {format: :json}`

Now apply this change at the controller level to always respond with JSON. Add `respond_to :json` at the top of your controller. Then use `respond_with` in your controller actions. `respond_with` will render `json` in all actions of your controller, as long as `respond_to :json` is defined at the top.

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @test = 'TESTING MY RAILS ROUTE'
    respond_with @test
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can also respond with `json` for an individual controller action only, by using `respond_to` within the controller action.

Comment: this gives me a 404 error saying: `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'respond_to' for LoginController:Class
Did you mean?  respond_to?):
  
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:2:in "<class:LoginController>"
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:1:in "<top (required)>"`

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: `Rails 5.1.4`. Update: I added `MimeResponds` to my Application controller so that it looks like this:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end` and error persists

Comment: Forgot the most important thing. You need to add `gem 'responders'` to your Gemfile. Updated my answer

Comment: can we start a chat?

Comment: We can start a chat, I'm on mobile, so hopefully I can do it from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163593/discussion-between-naji-and-grizzthedj).

Comment: Is it possible to return both JSON and HTML at the same time? I'm trying to implement a single react component with html generated from a rails view and i'm getting two get requests. One from the html page load and a second from an ajax call I have in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a convention that you need to choose the format to respond to if it's not the default. *By default*, Rails controller actions respond to `html` requests.

You should be able to configure this controller action to respond to both `html` and `Ajax` requests by adding the following code.

```
def index
  @test = 'TESTING MY RAILS ROUTE'

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js json: @test, status: :ok
    format.html
  end 
end
```

Comment: This gives me a 500 error, saying `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
  
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:7:in "block in index"
app/controllers/login_controller.rb:6:in "index"
`

Comment: @Naji That format.js line should read `format.js { json: @test, status: :ok` }